# Python module installed or not installed?

Tags: php, python

How can I check if my Python module is successfully installed.

I did:

```
python setup.py install
```

inside the folder where my module was downloaded.

Now, I can see that this resulted in a folder inside this location:

```
/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages (I can see my module folder is inside here)
```

Now I am using PHP to execute a script from this module:

```
exec("/usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/myModule script.py -v pixfx.xml 2>&1", $output, $return);
```

This runs the script.py file but does not load modules which this script requires.
This script has code like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
import sys 
import os 
import getopt 
import re 
from myModule.ttLib import TTFont // this is line60 as I have removed comments
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/myModule/script.py", line 60, in ? from myModule.ttLib import TTFont ImportError: No module named myModule.ttLib
```

Does this mean there could be some problem with the way my module was installed.
or
How do I check if the module is installed correctly....

I also tried to do this in SSH terminal:

```
help('modules')
```

This listed a load of modules but my module name was missing.

Any help?

****** EDIT {Solved} ******
Reinstalling the module solved it.
Its funny that what I used online SSH tool provided by Mediatemple, it didnt install the module correctly.
Later when I installed using Terminal from my Mac computer, everything worked.

Just thought I will add this for other who might face similar problem.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,
have you looked at my question history?
Whereever I have got a satisfactory answer, I have accepted it.

If not, there is no need for me to accept anything, right?

Comment: Go to your python shell,type import yourmodulename and press enter, if it runs successfully without any errors your module is installed and the paths are set correctly.

Comment: ok, i will try that, right now my computer is not able to connect to Shell. will have to try from home after a while.

Comment: when I do import in shell, it says command not found

Comment: You won't get "command not found" from your python shell. Type 'python' on your normal shell, then you are in your python shell. If you type a unrecognized command there, you'd get a "Name Error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the Python interpreter that you are calling sees your module by doing:

```
/usr/bin/python -c "import MyModule"
```

This command should simply import `MyModule/__init__.py` and not complain about MyModule not being found.

Since there are many modules in your code, you actually want to create a *package*, not a module.

To do so, you can simply add an empty `__init__.py` file in MyModule/ and all its subpackages, so as to indicate that you have a package (i.e. is a folder that contains many modules).

If your ttLib is in MyModule/myModule/ttLib/, you can do the same and add an empty `__init__.py` file in MyModule/ and MyModule/myModule/, so as to declare that MyModule and MyModule/myModule are packages; you can then simply do:

```
from MyModule.myModule.ttLib import …
```

Hope this helps!  The full documentation for packages can be found [on the official site](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: Hi,
the main file I am executing in script.py. Which resides in MyModule/myModule. THis script calls for another module which is inside MyModule/myModule/ttLib. The ttLib folder has a file called ____init____.py, this file contains a class called TTFont. This is the class that my script.py is trying to call by this line of code: "from myModule.ttLib import TTFont"

Comment: @ssdesign: I see.  You do need to put a (possibly empty) `__init__.py` file in all three directories, including MyModule/ and MyModule/myModule/ (this makes these directories Python packages).  Then, `from from MyModule.myModule.ttLib import TTFont` should work; it does on my machine (note the "double" `MyModule.myModule` prefix)…

Comment: @ssdesign: PS: You can check that your package is installed by doing `/usr/bin/python -c "import MyModule"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Python, but one way to debug this is to launch the python prompt, and do `import myModule` then, some simple command that uses that module's constructs. If this works then your module installation is not the issue. If not your module wasnt installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should see more than just the directory creation `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages`.

Comment: what exactly should I expect to see?

Comment: You should see a subdirectory there corresponding to the package in question, and you should see files in there corresponding to the implementation of that package.

Additionally, if you're referring explicitly to the /usr/lib/python2.4 directory, you should refer explicitly to that version of python if you call it, rather than assuming that the default version is 2.4.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I do see my module directory and its files.
And I also tried usr/bin/pythong as well as usr/bin/python2.4 .... both cases the module was not able to import

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell python to look under `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule/` for your module(s)?  (You need to put a *.pth file in `/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/` for that, or maybe you should not put them into an extra directory.)

Try the following in a python shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

What does that print?  Does it include `'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/MyModule'`?

Comment: IF you look at the PHP exec() commend in my question, I gave Python the path of the module. Is that correct? because the sace exec() command works offline.

Comment: See the question I added above... :)

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the module and everything works fine.
It seems the module was not installed correctly.